# How to create csv file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My output currently is:

```
echo "Time Taken to checkout svn repository repo_performance hosted on $host on `date` is : $Time_checkout seconds" >> log.csv
    echo "Time Taken to add $loopmax 10MB svn files in svn repository repo_performance  hosted on $host `date` is : $Time_add seconds" >> log.csv
    echo "Time Taken to commit $loopmax 10MB svn files in svn repository repo_performance  hosted on $host on `date` is : $Time_commit seconds" >> log.csv
```

But, I want to create a csv file which has Host, Date, Operation, Duration and its values in  the rows.

How can I make it using scripting ?

Answer (score 12):

You may just do:

```
echo "$host, `date`, checkout,$Time_checkout" >> log.csv
echo "$host, `date`, add, $Time_add" >> log.csv
echo "$host, `date`, cimmit, $Time_commits" >> log.csv
```

Comment: Thats fine. but how do I create my csv file headers as Host, Date, Operation, Duration

Answer (score 7):

you can try something like this;

```
printf "Host\tDate\tOperation\tDuration\n" >> log.csv
printf "$host\t$(date)\tTime Taken to checkout\t$Time_checkout\n" >> log.csv
printf "$host\t$(date)\tTime Taken to add $loopmax 10MB svn files\t$Time_add\n" >> log.csv
printf "$host\t$(date)\tTime Taken to commit $loopmax 10MB svn files\t$Time_commit\n" >> log.csv
```

Comment: `printf` seems better option instead of `echo -e`@Mustafa DOGRU

Answer (score 3):

You can also generalize Mig82's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67787201/452102) to support *variable* arguments like this:

```
# Usage: csv <items>

csv()
{
    local items=("$@")

    (
    IFS=,
    echo "${items[*]}"
    )
}

csv 1 "2 3" >> log.csv
```

Comment: used this with a slight adjustment to handle quoting:
```
    csv()
    {
        local items=("$@")
    
        # quote and escape as needed
        # https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180
        for i in "${!items[@]}"
        do
            if [[ "${items[$i]}" =~ [,\"] ]]
            then
                items[$i]=\"$(echo -n "${items[$i]}" | sed s/\"/\"\"/g)\"
            fi
        done
    
        (
        IFS=,
        echo "${items[*]}"
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is looking for CSV where values are in double quotes (`"`), you have to remove the outer quotes for the `echo` and use them (escaped) for each value instead, like this:

```sh
echo \"$host\",\"$date",\"checkout\",\"$checkout_time\" >> log.csv
echo \"$host\",\"$date",\"add\",\"$add_time\" >> log.csv
echo \"$host\",\"$date",\"commit\",\"$commit_time\" >> log.csv
```

I'd recommend writing a function to make your script less verbose and easier to read, like this.

```sh
write_csv(){
    echo \"$1\",\"$2\",\"$3\",\"$4\" >> log.csv
}
write_csv $host $date checkout $checkout_time
write_csv $host $date add $add_time
write_csv $host $date commit $commit_time
```

Answer (score 1):

used the answer from @Nishant with a slight adjustment to handle quoting:

```
    csv()
    {
        local items=("$@")
    
        # quote and escape as needed
        # https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180
        for i in "${!items[@]}"
        do
            if [[ "${items[$i]}" =~ [,\"] ]]
            then
                items[$i]=\"$(echo -n "${items[$i]}" | sed s/\"/\"\"/g)\"
            fi
        done
    
        (
        IFS=,
        echo "${items[*]}"
        )
    }
```